# SSH key authentication

Tags: linux, unix

I'm trying to get one server to be able to login to another server without using passwords.

I added the server 1 id_rsa.pub to server 2's authorized_keys. I chmod 600 server 2 authorized_keys file. But server 1 still can't login to server 2 without specifying a password. What am I doing wrong?

When I run ssh in debug mode, I get the following error:

```
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 624 bytes for a total of 1901
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: try 'ssh -v server2' sometimes this can help.  Is everything a default configuration or has there been modifications to ssh_config sshd_config?

Comment: Is your `.ssh` folder `700` as well as the home directory? If anything is writable by public above the `authorized_keys` file, then the auth will fail. If that's not it, you can run your `ssh` attempt in verbose mode with flag `-vvv` that may help identify the issue.

Comment: I get the following error

Comment: Wrong site, SO is for *programming questions*. Try http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions?page=2&sort=active or http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html), you may need to change the permissions of .ssh to 700 (`chmod 700 .ssh`)

Comment: should I be reloading the server?

Comment: did you follow all guide's steps?

Comment: I'm guessing maybe port 22 is not open. How do I check?

Comment: if port 22 was closed, you wouldn't be able to connect at all. Thing is that you can not connect without password.